# Exact analytical solution for the surface gravity of an oblate spheroid

Tags: newtonian-gravity, planets

I would like to know if an exact solution for the surface gravity force components of an oblate spheroid has been published and if not can anyone derive it here?

Assume an ideal rigid oblate sphere of uniform homogenous density, that is not rotating. We can always add in centripetal forces later if required.

The place to start would seem to be this exact general solution for the gravitational potential:

$$P = \frac{3 M}{(2 a e)} \left[B \left(1 - \frac{r^2}{(2 a^2 e^2)} + \frac{z^2}{(a^2 e^2}\right) + \frac{r^2}{(2 a^2 e^2)} \sin(B) \ \cos(B) -  \frac{z^2}{(2 a^2 e^2)} \tan(B) \right] \ \ $$

where $$B = \frac 1 2 \arccos \left( \sqrt{\frac{4 a^2 e^2}{r^2} + \left(1+\frac{a^2 e^2 + z^2}{r^2}\right)^2} -
 \ (a^2 e^2 + z^2)/r^2 \right),$$

$M$ is the mass, $a$ is the semi-major axis of the elliptical cross section of the oblate, "e" is the eccentricity of the oblate, $z$ is the vertical distance from the equatorial plane and $r$ is the horizontal distance from the vertical axis of rotational symmetry, of the point on the surface of the oblate.

This equation for the external potential of an oblate spheroid of homogenous density was derived by Gauss and Dirichlet. See [this 2018 paper by Hofmeister et al](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.pss.2018.01.005) that was linked to by @ProfRob in [a question about the gravity of an oblate sphere in the Astronomy forum](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/34745/).

I do not want solutions that depend on $J_2$ harmonic approximations as these are only generally valid for low eccentricity bodies.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Here is an article which refutes these claims. I am not an expert in GR so I don't really know how to assess these claims. But my linked article is peer reviewed, and the one wikipedia cites is not. I sent the article claiming galactic rotation is solved by GR to a friend who is an expert in GR, and without having spent a lot of time carefully checking, he said it "seems a bit crackpot"
https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.108.044056?fbclid=IwAR0dy7-xNlSPz_ffK1YkCCyHmShlMI6i4_Wqp9aNmn_TSyt5fLOQN9OY2Rc

Comment: The potential is obtained geometrically for a spheroid that uniform density, similar to how Newton derived the equation for his shell theorem. This is Newtonian analysis and there is no rotation involved. Just a rigid object that happens to be oblate.

Comment: @Sten There are only 5 parameters: M for mass, "a" is the semi-major axis of the elliptical cross section of the oblate. "e" is the eccentricity of the oblate. "z" is the vertical distance from the equatorial plane and "r" is the horizontal distance from the vertical rotation axis of the point on the surface of the oblate..

Comment: If you include descriptions of variables, don't put them into the comments, just edit them into your question so it can be more clear and self contained. Furthermore you can do better at linking previous questions by using the actual link functionality of the site, just provide author and name of papers/questions along with the links so they can be reconstructed in case of link rot.

Answer (score 6):

Using *Mathematica* to differentiate the exterior potential — after first verifying that it satisfies Laplace’s equation — I found that at the surface, where

$$z^2 = (1-e^2)(a^2-r^2),$$

the exact components of the gravitational force simplify to

$$F_r\big|_\text{surface} = -C_r\,\frac{r}{a}\,\frac{GMm}{a^2}$$

$$F_z\big|_\text{surface} = \mp C_z\,\frac{\sqrt{a^2-r^2}}{a}\,\frac{GMm}{a^2},$$

where $C_r$ and $C_z$ are dimensionless constants that depend on the eccentricity $e$ of the oblate spheroid:

$$C_r = \frac32 \frac{\sin^{-1}e-e\sqrt{1-e^2}}{e^3} = 1 + \frac{3}{10}e^2+O(e^4)$$

$$C_z = 3\,\frac{e-\sqrt{1-e^2}\sin^{-1}e}{e^3} = 1 + \frac25e^2+O(e^4).$$

Note that $r\equiv\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is the *cylindrical* radial coordinate.

In the formula for $F_z$, the negative sign is for the upper half (i.e., $z>0$) of the spheroid and the positive sign is for the lower half.

No approximations were involved in this calculation. The point of the series expansions is to show that the expected result follows in the spherical case when $e=0$.

In the opposite limit $e\to 1$, one has $C_r \to 3\pi/4$ and $C_z \to 3$.

I have no idea whether these results for the surface gravity are previously known, but I'd guess that they have been published somewhere.

The following graph shows the dependence of these constants on the eccentricity. The blue curve is $C_r$ and the gold curve is $C_z$.

[image]

I've expressed both $F_r$ and $F_z$ at the surface in terms of the radial coordinate $r$. But one could just as well express them in terms of $z$ (or a polar angle $\theta$).

If one uses the equation for the surface to express $F_z$ there in terms of $z$ instead of $r$, one finds that $F_z$ is simply proportional to $z$, in the same way that $F_r$ is proportional to $r$.

At first I was surprised by the fact that such a complicated external potential gives rise to simple linear relations for the surface force components. However, once I looked at the *internal* potential, I realized that it's obvious!

As the Hofmeister paper mentions, the internal potential is much simpler:  $B$ is just a constant inside! (It's equal to $\sin^{-1}e$.) This means that the internal potential is simply quadratic in both $r$ and $z$, so the internal force components are linear.

The gravitational force does not change discontinuously as one goes from outside to inside. (For proof, walk down to your basement. Do you feel a discontinuity in gravity? A spheroidal *shell* would cause a discontinuity.) Therefore to compute the surface gravity one can use the much simpler interior potential. This way is so simple that you can do it by hand rather than using a computer algebra system.

As a visualization of an oblate spheroid’s gravity, the following image shows the contour lines of the potential — both interior and exterior — and the vectors for surface gravity, for a spheroid with eccentricity 0.9:

[image]

The white ellipse is the surface of the spheroid. The vertical white line is an artifact of not taking sufficient care when evaluating the potential on the $z$-axis.

Note that the force vectors are orthogonal to the equipotential surfaces, not to the surface of the spheroid. And note that in general they don't point toward the center of the spheroid.

Comment: Nice work @Ghoster +1  I checked your simplified equations and they are spot on. I think together, we are the first to come up with an exact solution for the surface gravity of a homogenous density oblate spheroid of arbitrary ellipticity.

Comment: @KDP Thanks! I've added to my answer.

Comment: Nice idea to find a simpler solution for the surface gravity by using the interior potential. Wish I had thought of that! So the force is orthogonal to the equi-potential surface ($(a'e')^2 = (3/5) (ae)^2$) (Eq26) and not to the equi-force surface ($(a'e')^2 = (9/10) (ae)^2$) (Eq27)?

Comment: $\vec F= -\vec\nabla U$. The gradient of a potential function is always orthogonal to the equipotential surfaces.

Comment: "At first I was surprised by the fact that such a complicated external potential gives rise to simple linear relations for the surface force components." I was too until I realised that the oblate is the equilibrium shape when centrifugal force matches gravitational force and the centrifugal has a linear relationship with r ($F_{centrifugal} = m \omega^2 r$) so the surface gravity must too.

Answer (score 4):

The first step is to find the partial derivative wrt r of the exterior gravitational potential of the oblate, derived by Gauss and Dirichlet.

The next step is to substitute the value of z (The vertical coordinate) as a function of r (the horizontal coordinate).

$$z(r) =  \sqrt{(a^2 - a^2 e^2)*(1 - r^2/a^2)}$$

which is readily obtained from the definition of an ellipse.

A similar procedure to find the partial derivative wrt to z is used to find the vertical component Fz of the force:

The exact result for the horizontal component $F_r$ of the surface gravitational force can be seen in this [Mathematica worksheet](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/kpegrume/Published/OblateForce.nb) , but I recommend the simplified equations found by @Ghoster in his answer.

In short $F_z \propto M \sqrt{a^2-r^2}$ and  $F_r \propto M r$.

While it may be initially surprising to see that the horizontal component (blue curve below) **increases** with distance from the centre, it becomes obvious this **must** be the case, since centrifugal force (CF) also increases linearly with increasing distance from the centre as per  $CF \propto \omega^2 r$ and a fluid oblate rotating body is the result of the equilibrium of those forces.

The resultant total force Ft is easily found using Pythogorus:

$Ft = \sqrt{Fr^2 +Fz^2}$

[image]

And the component (Fc) of the total force that points directly at the centre is found using:

$Fc = \cos\left( \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{Fz}{Fr}\right)  + 
      \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{-r}{z}\right) - \pi/2 \right) Ft $
$= \cos\left( \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{Fz}{Fr}\right)  + 
      \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{-r}{\sqrt{(a^2 - a^2 e^2) (1 - r^2/a^2)}}\right) - \pi/2 \right) Ft $

Below is a plot of Fr, Fz, Ft, Fc and z, from r=0 to r=a:.

[image]

This plot is colour coded the same as the force vectors in the diagram above it. The magenta curve (z) is the elliptical profile of the oblate at e = 0.99. The gold curve (Fz) is the vertical component of the surface force and drops off to zero going towards the equator. The blue curve is the horizontal component (Fr) that points at the vertical z axis. This component steadily increases gong from he centre to the equator. The green curve (Ft) is the resultant for Fr and Fz and only drops off by about 20% going from the centre out to the equator. The red curve (Fc) is the component of the total surface force that points directly at the centre and after an initial drop off starts to *increase* linearly going outwards.

If we naively assumed the central force was proportional to $GMm/R^2$ (where R = $\sqrt{r^2+z^2}$ ), then the required balancing centrifugal force would require a velocity of $u = \sqrt{\frac{G M m}{R}}$, while using the central pointing force Fc derived above, the required velocity to produce the required balancing centrifugal force is given by $v = \sqrt{ Fc 
 \ \ R}$ and these two velocity curve profiles are plotted below for comparison:

[image]

The classic assumption (blue) for stable orbital velocities, drops off with increasing distance from the centre, while the exact solution presented here, shows the required balancing velocities increase with increasing distance from the centre. As a side note, it is worth noting that orbits around a galaxy spend 50% of their time above the equatorial plane and the other 50% below the equatorial plane and there is plenty of potential for collisions at the cross over points.

As a sanity check it is possible to find the solution using the equipotential surface ($(a'e')2 = 3/5 (a e)^2% as described in the paper) and by assuming the resultant force is normal to this equipotential surface, the results are similar for direction.

A typical elliptical galaxy with a central bulge could be modelled by adding the above equations for the flattened disk, to the usual $F = GMm/r^2$ to allow for the extra mass of the bulge at the centre modelled as a sphere. By using e=1, a model of a flat disk is produced, which is otherwise very difficult to find an analytical solution for the general case.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152050/discussion-on-answer-by-kdp-exact-analytical-solution-for-the-surface-gravity-of); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.